# redux-actions createAction default parameters in payloadCreator function (typeScript)

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-actions

if i generate an action as such:

```
export const updateParticularObjectValue = createAction(
    UPDATE_PARTICULAR_VALUE,
    (id: string, amount: number, reason: string = 'default') => { 
        return { id, value: amount, reason }; 
    },
);
```

for some reason my IDE (and indeed, my typescript compiler) is complaining that calling the action creator expects only two arguments when i pass the third explicitly.  i would like the creator to take the third argument optionally... is there a way to do this using the redux-actions `createAction` function, or do i need to manually build the action creator?

P.S. -- also this syntax causes the same result:

```
export const updateParticularObjectValue = createAction(
    UPDATE_PARTICULAR_VALUE,
    (id: string, amount: number, reason?: string) => { 
        return { id, value: amount, reason: reason || 'default' }; 
    },
);
```

seems like making the third argument optional in any way does not translate in typescript -- it's treated as nonexistent and calls to the function forbid including it.  is there a way around this?

P.P.S. -- if you can 'fool' the typescript compiler (in my case by defining the function interface in a component's Props type when using 'connect' in a react component) it works fine, it just doesn't pass the compiler's smell test when calling it explicitly -- seems there's no real reason this should occur.

P.P.P.S. -- at this point, i've found a workable solution.  i am, however, still interested in why this is a limitation of createAction's typescript implementation and if there are any alternate solutions that would be better/smarter for this situation.  a good explanation would be educational for myself and, likely, others.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this, using an arrow function return `createAction` function:

```
interface ActionProps {
    id: string;
    amount: number;
    reason: string;
}

export const updateParticularObjectValue = (props: ActionProps) => (createAction('UPDATE_PARTICULAR_VALUE', {
    id: props.id,
    value: props.amount,
    reason: props.reason
}));
```

Comment: will this create a new action creator on every call?  additionally, does it matter?  this may be called many, many times

Comment: @derelict https://github.com/redux-utilities/redux-actions/blob/master/src/createAction.js I've never used `redux-actions`, but it seems using similar syntax internally. So I don't think it's a problem. Give a try first?

Comment: thanks @FisNaN -- going to hold out to see if anyone can help me with the tech on why it's not working as is, but appreciate the effort.  grokking the source ref you provided now.

Answer (score 0):

So based on @FisNaN's original response, it seems the cleanest solution is to wrap the action creator in a container function and allow the action creator itself to consider all inputs mandatory, e.g.:

```
// allow a default
export const updateObjectValue = (id: string, amount: number, reason: string = 'default') => {
    return updateObjectValueWithReason(id, amount, reason);
}
// do it for real
const updateObjectValueWithReason = createAction(
    UPDATE_PARTICULAR_VALUE,
    (id: string, amount: number, reason: string) => { 
        return { id, value: amount, reason }; 
    },
);
```

if you really need your reducer to determine the default value you can always create two action creators and let your wrapper choose which to fire:

```
// allow a default
export const updateObjectValue = (id: string, amount: number, reason?: string) => {
    return typeof reason === 'undefined'
        ? updateObjectValueWithoutReason(id, amount)
        : updateObjectValueWithReason(id, amount, reason);
}
// take a reason and send it through the action
const updateObjectValueWithReason = createAction(
    UPDATE_PARTICULAR_VALUE,
    (id: string, amount: number, reason: string) => { 
        return { id, value: amount, reason }; 
    },
);
// send no reason through the action, let reducer decide
const updateObjectValueWithoutReason = createAction(
    UPDATE_PARTICULAR_VALUE,
    (id: string, amount: number) => { 
        return { id, value: amount }; 
    },
);
```

I'm still not 100% clear on why the typescript typedef returned by the createAction function omits optional params entirely, but this methodology should allow you to use optional params however you'd like in your actionCreators.